# D3: Confidence ellipse, how to orient?

Tags: d3.js, svg

My plan is to draw a 95% confidence ellipse atop my basic d3 scatter plot. I initially thought it would be super easy to draw a confidence ellipse in D3, because there is a dedicated SVG ellipse to work with. However, things proved difficult as I could only create axis-aligned ellipses. While not rocket science, the math for determining the correct orientation for the ellipse is still somewhat involving. Luckily I found [this great guide](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/) on how to calculate, and also this reference picture:

[image]

I wanted to take baby steps first, so I left the math aside for a moment and just tried to eye-ball the ellipse over the scatter plot like so:

```
graphGroupG.append('ellipse')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')')
    .attr({cx:xScale(0), cy:yScale(0), rx:xScale(-6), ry:yScale(6)})
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 3)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

And despite tinkering with all `cx`,`cy`,`rx`,`ry` combinations, all my ellipses were axis-aligned and not oriented diagonally as would be required to serve as a proper confidence ellipse. I wonder if there is some secret `orientation` attribute that I'm not aware of.

**Question:** How can I use d3's ellipse svg such that I am able to set the ellipse `.attr()` to the required confidence ellipse coordinates (implying diagonal orientation). If the dedicated ellipse shape doesn't work, would a `path` approach be viable?

I would appreciate a plunker or block for proof of concept. I have looked all over the place and didn't find anything of the sort.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `rotate`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado On your suggestion, I am using `rotate` to hold me over until I can find a programmatic way to handle it. I have eye-balled it and am fairly happy with it, but in the future if I have a new data set, I will benefit greatly from a method that sets the coordinates / orients the ellipse to enclose 95% of the data. Otherwise `rotate` will require me to trial and error all over again.

Comment: In that case, create an elliptical arc: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands

Comment: You don't need to use trial and error to find the angle of rotation. The algorithm you linked to tells you how to calculate it.